# lua-widow-control: is it possible to change warnings into infos

Tags: luatex, warnings

I am using the nice package `lua-widow-control` to slightly improve the appearance of the document. However, the warning messages "Widow/Orphan/Broken Hyphen NOT removed on page ..." was too long (contain too many lines), and when the document becomes lengthy, a large number of such warning messages can sometimes drown out other important warnings. I wonder if there is some way to change these messages from the level "Warning" into "Info" when the document is not finalized?

Below is an example of such a warning message.

```
Widow/Orphan/Broken Hyphen NOT removed on page 10
[10] [11]
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'page.11'
[11] (./the-document.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 4014 words of node memory still in use:
   9 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 1 local_par, 4 glue, 4 kern, 2 penalty, 2 sub_mlist, 1 margin_kern, 6 glyph, 1546 attribute, 76 glue_spec, 102 attribute_list, 1 write, 10 user_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:31,2:99181,3:1431,4:947,5:244,6:94,7:8887,8:42,9:4342,10:45,11:552
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Sans.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/texgyrepagella-math.otf></Users/username/Library/Fonts/PalatinoSansLTPro-Regular.OTF></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newcomputermodern/NewCMMono10-Bold.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf></Users/username/Library/Fonts/pala.TTF></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newcomputermodern/NewCMMono10-Regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreheros-bold.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreheros-regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/texgyrepagella-math.otf></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/texgyrepagella-math.otf></Users/username/Library/Fonts/palabi.TTF></Users/username/Library/Fonts/palai.TTF></Users/username/Library/Fonts/pala.TTF></Users/username/Library/Fonts/palab.TTF></Users/username/Library/Fonts/SourceHanSerif.ttc></Users/username/Library/Fonts/SourceHanSerif.ttc></Users/username/Library/Fonts/SourceHanSerif.ttc></Users/username/Library/Fonts/SourceHanSerif.ttc></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eurb10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eurb7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>
Output written on the-document.pdf (...).
SyncTeX written on the-document.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on the-document.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'the-document.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'the-document.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'the-document.log'
Latexmk: Index file 'the-document.idx' was written
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'the-document.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

Comment: It is much easier to check and test solutions if you provide a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would like to provide one yet I don't know how to produce a minimal document with an unremovable widow/orphan so as to trigger this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message comes from

```
--- When we are unable to remove a widow/orphan, print a warning
---
--- @return nil
local function remove_widows_fail()
    warning("Widow/Orphan/Broken Hyphen NOT removed on page " .. pagenum)
```

in `texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lua-widow-control/lua-widow-control.lua`

as such it is a locally defined function call (`warning`) inside the `local` declaration. So by design you can't really patch that from the outside.

You could however copy that file to the current directory (or anywhere earlier in the path) then around line 242 you see

```
        warning = function(str) luatexbase.module_warning(lwc.name, str) end
        info = function(str) luatexbase.module_info(lwc.name, str) end
```

and if you change `_warning` to `_info` then `warning()` will be like `info()` and only write to the log

Comment: note any changes should be compatble with the [Mozilla LIcense](https://github.com/gucci-on-fleek/lua-widow-control/blob/master/licences/MPL-2.0.txt)